# jQuery syntax help - filmstrip gallery code

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a simple gallery and can't figure out what is wrong with my jQuery syntax.

When the user clicks a thumbnail (one of the first three list items), I want to `clone()` the image and caption, and paste it into `li.expand` (the full-size image).

The first two lines of my jQuery function are working (i.e. the "selected" class) but the last two lines don't seem to be doing anything. Am I using `$(this)` wrong?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="gallery2">
        <li>
            <img src="img/1.jpg" />
            <p>Caption 1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/2.jpg" />
            <p>Caption 2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/3.jpg" />
            <p>Caption 3</p>
        </li>

        <li class="expand">
            <!-- This space will be filled with whatever thumbnail is selected -->
        </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".gallery2 li").click(function () {
    $(".gallery2 li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(".gallery2 li.expand").html().remove();
    $(this).html().clone().appendTo(".gallery2 li.expand");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) returns a string, not a jQuery object. Perhaps you mean to use [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children)? Additionally, rather than use `.children().remove()`, you can use [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty). With those changes:

```js
$(".gallery2 li").click(function () {
    $(".gallery2 li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(".gallery2 li.expand").empty();
    $(this).children().clone().appendTo(".gallery2 li.expand");
});
```

You might also consider using [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to select sibling elements:

```js
$(".gallery2 li").click(function () {
    var me = $(this);
    me.siblings().removeClass("selected");
    me.addClass('selected');
    me.siblings('.expand').empty().append(me.children().clone());
});
```

And if we're going to go to all that trouble, why not make it more generic by turning it into a plugin?

```js
$.fn.gallerize = function() {
    this.on('click', 'li', function() {
        var me = $(this);
        me.siblings().removeClass('selected');
        me.addClass('selected');
        me.siblings('.expand').empty().append(me.children().clone());
    });
};
```

Then it's this simple to make a gallery:

```js
$('.gallery2').gallerize();
```

**Try it [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCnqX/).**

Comment: Wonderful. I didn't know that html() returned a string, thanks!